# java multiple methods and instances

Tags: java

I'm following a series of tutorials on multiple methods and instances. The author didn't elaborate the details about some elements.

Why do you think would he put the method setName in a "public void" and then get the return using the "public String getName". Why didn't he just place the return randomName inside public void and in public void saying method declare the string g?

```
public class voidvoid {

private String randomName;

public void setName(String name){
    randomName = name;

}
public String getName () {
    return randomName;
}

public void saying () {
    System.out.printf("you are %s", getName());
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using public void to set the value of a variable and public  to get the value of a variable is the 'correct' way to do it. You can search "getters and setters in java" for more on the topic. Basically this provides public access to the stored name in terms of getting and setting the value of the variable. The method saying() is showing a use of the getter method, in this case, getName(). Note that the variable itself was declared private. This means that unless you extend this class, you have no access to the variable from outside this class except through the getter and setter. Say for example you do not like the name Fred. Inside your setName(String name) method you could say:

```
if(name.equals("Fred") {
   randomName = "Jon Doe";
}
```

Any time someone tries to set the name "Fred", it will be saved as "Jon Doe" instead. If they had direct access to the variable, they could just set the value to "Fred" any time.
This means you have ultimate control over what goes into the variable through your method.

Answer (score 3):

It is called Encapsulation.

> Hiding the internals of the object protects its integrity by
>   preventing users from setting the internal data of the component into
>   an invalid or inconsistent state. A benefit of encapsulation is that
>   it can reduce system complexity, and thus increases robustness, by
>   allowing the developer to limit the interdependencies between software
>   components.

More information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)

Answer (score 1):

When a method set an attribute of a class it is called `setter` method :

```
public void setName(String name)
```

As you can only set the `randomename` attribute of the class using this method it usually need not to have a return type . But you can surely add a return type if you want. Such as :

```
//this method will return true if the `randomname` was not set previously 
//otherwise false
public boolean setName(String name) {
    if (null == randomname )  { 
        randomname = name;
        return true;  
    }
    else return false;    
}
```

And alike the setter method if you can get an attribute using a method it is usually called `getter` method :

```
public String getName(String name)
```

Saying method is used to print the `randomname` attribute. It was needed as you can't print the `randomname` outside of the class scope as it is private :

```
//this will print the value of randomname
public void saying ()

//another scenario
voidvoid foo = new voidvoid () ;
foo.setName("Hello world") ;

//this line will generate an erro
System.out.println (foo.randomname) ; 

//this will compile fine
foo.saying () ;

//you can also achieve the same result using getName
System.out.println (foo.getName() ) ;
```

Having a setter/getter method for a `private` attribute is `mandatory` if you want to `retrieve/set` the attribute , but `optional` for `public` attributes but in my opinion this is a `good practice` to have it.

Comment: It's also common to return `this` from setter methods, so they can be chained.

Answer (score 0):

There's more to it than just showing the end user the value of what's been encapsulated.  In many programs, output to stdout (which is where System.out is putting output) is *never* see by the end user.  Your object may need that `String` for later reference, so pulling it out instead of giving it output to stdout would be far more beneficial.

As for `getName` and `setName`  - these are **accessors** and **mutators**, respectively.

An accessor needs to retrieve information about a specific variable, and so the expected return type is the type of variable you need.  Since you're getting back a `String`, you would expect that `getName` returns `String`, as the variable `randomName` is a `String`.

A mutator needs only to change the value of the internal variable, often on some condition.  Nothing really needs to be returned here, hence the return value is `void`.  Often you will see mutators that return `boolean` to indicate success or failure, but in the examples I've seen it used, that return value is largely ignored.

Answer (score 0):

> Why didn't he just place the return randomName inside public void

I don't understand the question. He placed it inside the `public static String getName()` method. Where else could he put it?

> in public void saying method declare the string g?

Because that would make it a local variable instead of an instance member, so you couldn't set it with another method.